# combining groupby() and bi_class

Tags: r, dplyr

The code below returns what I need. However, when I tried to include groupby() function, I got an error:

```
Error in bi_class(., IDD_nhmap, x = Zip_Black, y = svi, style = "quantile",  : 
  A logical scalar must be supplied for 'keep_factors'. Please provide either 'TRUE' or 'FALSE'.
```

```r
# The code before including groupby function
    IDD_nhmap <- bi_class(IDD_nhmap, x = Zip_Black, y = svi, style = "quantile", dim = 3)

   
# The code after including groupby function

     IDD_nhmap <- IDD_nhmap %>%
      group_by(ProjectID) %>%
      bi_class(IDD_nhmap, x = Zip_Black, y = svi, style = "quantile", dim = 3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**: remove the `IDD_nhmap` from your call to `bi_class`.

In your second use, you are passing the frame to `bi_class` *twice* which is incorrect.

In a `%>%`-pipe, the data as it appears in the pipe is passed as the first argument to the next function; this can be specified (or repeated) by using the `.` placeholder. Your code therefore is really something like this:

```r
IDD_nhmap <- IDD_nhmap %>%
  group_by(., ProjectID) %>%
  bi_class(., IDD_nhmap, x = Zip_Black, y = svi, style = "quantile", dim = 3)
```

For `group_by`, this makes sense: it expects the first argument to be a frame (equivalent to `.data = .`) and all remaining unnamed arguments are taken as the symbols for grouping variables.

For `bi_class`, the `.` is placed in the first argument (`.data = .` again), which means *your* first unnamed argument is interpreted as the next not-yet-used argument. The arguments listed in `?bi_class` are:

```
bi_class(.data, x, y, style, dim = 3, keep_factors = FALSE, dig_lab = 3)
```

Since you explicitly name `x`, `y`, `style`, and `dim`, the first unused argument is `keep_factors`, so your call is effectively:

```r
IDD_nhmap <- IDD_nhmap %>%
  group_by(., ProjectID) %>%
  bi_class(., keep_factors = IDD_nhmap, x = Zip_Black, y = svi, style = "quantile", dim = 3)
```

which is obviously not correct. Your first step should be

```r
IDD_nhmap <- IDD_nhmap %>%
  group_by(ProjectID) %>%
  bi_class(x = Zip_Black, y = svi, style = "quantile", dim = 3)
```

However, you are still not likely to get what you are hoping for. While I don't know the `bi_class` function personally, it does not look for the grouping attributes that `dplyr::group_by` adds to the data, so the results from this call will be the same as your first (ungrouped) call. A hasty attempt at this might be:

```r
IDD_nhmap <- IDD_nhmap %>%
  group_by(., ProjectID) %>%
  do(bi_class(., IDD_nhmap, x = Zip_Black, y = svi, style = "quantile", dim = 3))
```

though `do` is superseded. Untested, perhaps you can try

```r
IDD_nhmap <- IDD_nhmap %>%
  group_by(., ProjectID) %>%
  summarize(
    bi = bi_class(cur_data(), IDD_nhmap, x = Zip_Black, y = svi, style = "quantile", dim = 3)
  )
```

to get a nested result (`bi` will be a list-column), over to you how you intend to utilize this.